# ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'S3Fs'. The S3Fs package is required to handle S3 files. Use pip or conda to install S3Fs

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, pip, aws-cloud9, python-s3fs

I am using AWS Cloud9 as my IDE.

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
# import s3fs
# s3_ob=boto3.resource('s3',aws_access_key_id="xxxxxxxxxx",aws_secret_access_key="xxxxxxxxxxxx")
client=boto3.client('s3')
path="s3://xxxxxx/FL_insurance_sample.csv"

df=pd.read_csv(path)
# df.head()
print(df)`
```

While I am able to get the output CSV file in Pycharm, when I use the same code in Cloud9 IDE on AWS I get the error mentioned in title.

I have installed the S3Fs using the pip install S3Fs and when I do "pip list"
it does give me the list installed which contains S3Fs so I am confused,
why am I getting this error when the module is already installed and it shows in the pip list,
and I also tried uncommenting the import S3Fs and still the same error is there.

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome Adithya. Have you tried reinstalling with `pip3 install s3fs --user`. I assume you are using latest version of Python 3, so you should be using `pip3` instead. Furthermore, check that you have activated the conda environment correctly by checking `conda env list` will show you the list of environments you have and the one with * is the currently active one

Comment: it shows pip 3 command not found in the bash,tried both pip3 install s3fs --user  and  conda env list @carkod

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Installed the `s3fs` package using `pip`.  It was showing up in `pip list`. But it did not show up when I did: `conda list`.

I resolved this problem by doing the following steps:

1. Installed the s3fs dependecy using `conda install -c conda-forge s3fs`
2. Restarted kernel
3. Imported `s3fs`and `pandas`
4. Read the `csv` file which was in my s3 bucket.

PS: It was library issue.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue except s3fs *does* show up in both pip list and conda list. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: try this: create a new environment altogether and then switch to it. see if this issue is fixed. most of the times the problem is with the environment.

Comment: Thanks, actually a new env didn't do the trick, but I did need to run "conda install pip" in the env itself first, then use that env's version of pip to install s3fs.

Comment: @SaurabhJain,  I folowed exactely the solution by installing s3fs on my laptop, but i have the same erro : [ERROR] ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'fsspec'.  Use pip or conda to install fsspec.

Answer (score 8):

```
pip3 install s3fs
```

solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to install the package. Open you Command Prompt and type:
`pip install fsspec`

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was missing `aiobotocore` package.

```
pip install aiobotocore
```